# Are Android AIDL/Binder Interface Objects thread-safe?

Tags: android

If I have a Binder object representing a Remote Interface (to an Android service or a callback interface to a remote client), would I need explicit synchronization when sending IPC via this object from multiple threads, or is that taken care of by the underlying Android component?

Answer (score 4):

A Bounded service is implemented using Binder class if we want client and service to be run in the same process and do not want to perform concurrent IPC across different applications.
So the thread (in the client) which calls the service method will be blocked until it returns. 
There may be multiple threads spawned in the client(activity) programmitically each of which calls the service method at any instant of time. Therefore the service should be implemented such that it is thread-safe because there may be multiple threads calling the service method at a time.
Conclusion is android doesn't take care of synchronization when Binder class is extended to implement the Bounded Service.

A Bounded service is implemented using AIDL if we want to allow clients from different applications to access the service for IPC and want to handle multithreading in the service. Conclusion is android doesn't take care of synchronization when AIDL is used to implement the Bounded Service.

Answer (score 1):

Calling a Binder RPC method in Android is threadsafe, you can issue the call from multiple threads without synchronizing.

On the receiving end--assuming the Service is in a different process as it usually is--you get calls from a pool of Binder threads regardless of how it was called on the callers side. This means that your Service could have multiple calls running simultaneously so be careful on that side.

More info in Android Docs: [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#ThreadSafe)